# How to fix the error to run jsoup in android

Tags: android, jsoup

I am getting a error to run this code. When i run this code it was terminate.
In this line i get error "Document doc= Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com").get();" .

How to solve this ,I am trying in android studio.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    Document doc= Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com").get();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }


        });

    }

}
```

give the access INTERNET in androidManifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`

> ERROR at runtime when i press the button:

```
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 8556
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jsoup/Jsoup;
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$1.getWebsite(MainActivity.java:32)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:27)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    enter code here

/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8556 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show how is your build.gradle file? Also, looking at the stack trace, it looks like you're running your code on the main thread. Look for [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

Here is an example: [this](http://imranjaved728.blogspot.com/2013/10/web-scrapping-in-android-using-jsoup.html)